# How can I make email requests work with dynamic HTML responses?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, amazon-ses

I am sending HTML email using AWS SES (Nodejs). It's working with static HTML, but I don't know how to make it work with a dynamic HTML.

nodejs file

```
HTML = "..." // load external html file
var params = {
    Destination: {/* required */
        ToAddresses:[abc@gmail.com, test@gmail.com]
    },
    Message: {/* required */
        Body: { /* required */
            Html: {
                Data: HTML,
                Charset: 'UTF-8'
            },
        },
        Subject: { /* required */
            Data: 'Test email', /* required */
            Charset: 'UTF-8'
        }
    },
    Source: "myemail@gmail.com"
}

ses.sendEmail(params, function(err, data) {
  // If something goes wrong, print an error message.
  if(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  } else {
    console.log("Email sent! Message ID: ", data.MessageId);
  }
});
```

html file

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <h1>Amazon SES Test</h1>
  <p>Your order is placed.
    <a href='https://example.com/id=1234125'>View your order</a> 
   </p>
</body>
</html>
```

My question: how to pass href from nodejs file to html file as a variable.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a placeholder in your HTML, e.g: `<a href="HREF_PLACEHOLDER">...</a>`.

And then use string.replace() on your HTML to replace it with the actual href you want.

For example:

```
function dynamicHtml(href) {
  return HTML.replace("HREF_PLACEHOLDER", href);
}
```

And instead of passing HTML to your params object, pass it `dynamicHtml()`

Comment: yea, it's a solution, simple than I thought :)